# ios cordova app redirect and opens in browser

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I have a cordova app. Its pointed to a web page.  But the web page goes out and pulls a value, actually depending on a value which page to redirect to. 
Either A.html or B.html depending on the value.

The problem I'm having is in the cordova index.html page I have javascript trying to redirect to the new page.  After I have pulled the value, redirect to the page string that came in.

```
window.location.replace("/site/" + this.responseText);
```

The problem I having is in ios, the splash screen comes up, the app shows for a second then it opens up a browser to the new page. I want the page to say inside the app?

The solutions on stackoverflow give some ideas to handle the click event and catch it. There is no real click event. 
I also would like to do it just in JavaScript.

Any idea?

Comment: How are you attempting to connect to the page in order to find the value? It sounds as though you want to wait until that response before attempting to do the redirect. In that case, you would need to make use of a `promise`.

Comment: Yeah kind of.  The main page (that does the redirect) just has text saying "Loading".  Its just waiting until after the new page has come back.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this in cordova is through config.xml
You have to have

```
<allow-navigation href="http://example.com/*" />
```

This will allow those external sites to still show up in the app WebView.

I also had to change the intent.

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

Cordova sets these up to default any link to open outside.
Changing to only the URLs that need to go outside the app.

```
<allow-intent href="https://www.yahoo.com/*" />
```